# OpenAI API error: keep getting timeouts while using openai api ver.4.20.1 in node.js

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am keep getting timeouts only even if I asked the simple questions like 1+1.

```
const OpenAI = require('openai');

async function chat(req, res) {
  try {
    const openai = new OpenAI({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });

    const userMessage = req.body.prompt;

    const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4", 
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: userMessage }],
    });

    res.json(chatCompletion.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in OpenAI API request:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error processing your request');
  }
}

module.exports = { chat };
```

Where did I got wrong?

I want to mimic the chat gpt using the openai api. the code is in node.js, and the version of the openai library is 4.20.1.